# Proof related to minimum and maximum degree of vertices of an undirected graph

Tags: graph-theory

I don't know how to proceed for this problem. I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

> Let $\delta$ and $\Delta$ be the minimum and maximum degree of the
>   vertices of an undirected graph G.
>
> Show that $\delta \leq \frac{2\left | E(G) \right |}{\left | V(G)
> \right |}\leq \Delta $.

Answer (score 9):

HINT: Use the basic fact relating degrees of vertices to number of edges: $$\sum_{v\in V(G)}\deg v=2|E(G)|\;.$$ What are the minimum and maximum possible values of the sum?

Answer (score 1):

Let $e$ be the no. of edges.
Let $v$ be the no. of vertices.
Let $mn$ be min degree of vertex in graph.
Let $mx$ be the max degree of vertex in graph.
 every vertex's degree must lie between this min and max limit
$\min\leq \deg(v)\leq \max$
$\min\leq 2e\leq \max$  // using the above hint
thus for n vertices in a graph,
$n(\min)\leq 2e\leq n(\max)$ and so
$\min \leq 2\frac{e}{n}\leq \max$

Comment: I've edited your answer. It was very difficult to read, but feel free to edit further if you think I have changed some meaning. Also, you may want to look in to latex, which you can use to make writing maths nicer

Comment: welcome to [MATHEMATICS](http://math.stackexchange.com/). You can use [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for more information too.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try a slightly different answer. Consider $\mu$ the average degree, so

$$
\mu = \frac{1}{|V(G)|} \sum_{v \in V(G)} \deg(v)
$$

by [Euler's handshaking lemma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma) (as mentioned in [@Brian M. Scott's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/237118/408160)),

$$
\mu = \frac{1}{|V(G)|} 2 |E(G)|
$$

Since the average must lie within the extrema ($\delta \le \mu \le \Delta$), the result follows.